# Tooltip inside popover bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I'm trying to put a Tooltip inside a Popover and it's not working.

Outside of the popover it's working 100%.

Just like that: 
http://www.finecolor.com.br/novo
First try the tooltip above menu, then click on Contact and try the tooltip...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

It worked using this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('body').tooltip( {selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'} );
});
</script>
```